# Add extra fields to a node display

Tags: 7, nodes

I want to add extra fields when a node is displayed, the data of this fields are fetched from an external db.

I'm uncertain if I've to use the `hook_node_view_alter` function or `hook_node_view`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand if the extra fields to add are in the node form or into the page(display of node). If it's the first thing I think you can use hook_form_alter to add the extra fields and in the second case you can use hook_preprocess_node to add the variables to 'send' to the front-end of site.

Comment: It's the second case, so I understand that the `hook_preprocess_node` is the right function

Comment: However, I'm using `hook_node_view` and it seems effective

Answer (score 0):

You could use hook_preprocess_node and add variables that you could use in a node template.

Comment: I'm using `hook_node_view` and it works, what is the advantage in using `hook_preprocess_node`?

Comment: If you've got it working, I'd say it's a matter of preference. No real advantage either way. With hook_node_view, you add fields to the node object. With hook_preprocess_node, you can add variables for direct use in the template.